# Css position, slight off from Web-kit and FF

Tags: css, firefox, webkit, cross-browser, positioning

I have a table with images inside the a  that are positioned with absolute, so they will be right on the border of each column.  My issue is in FF i have them lined up just right and in the Web-kit browsers they are pushed to the right about 6-7 pixels?  Any ideas why, usually I don't have issues between these browsers.
And I am using a CSS Reset/

**EDIT: After further review it seems like FF does NOT recognize a position:relative to a table but will for a DIV.  Webkit browsers do recognize position:relative set to a table.  So in FF the position was based off the DIV and in Webkit browsers it was based off the TABLE.

Has anyone come across this before?????**

HTML:

```
<td class="tri-img">
<img class="one" src="img/triangles/triangle20.png" alt="" >
<span class="tri-val one">30&#37;</span>
</td>
<td class="tri-img">
<img class="two" src="img/triangles/triangle20.png" alt="" >
<span class="tri-val one">30&#37;</span>
</td>
```

CSS:

```
.tri-graph .tri-col td.tri-img{
    position: relative;
    color:#ffffff;
}
.wrap-graph.relative img{
    position: absolute;
    cursor: pointer;
    bottom:1px;
    z-index: 1;
}

.wrap-graph.relative img.one{
    left:53px;
}
.wrap-graph.relative img.two{
    left:91px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would say it has something to do with the table.

Try setting all padding and margins in the table to 0.

.....Just saw the reset.css part.. hmmm

Comment: do you have anything wrapping that html?

Comment: The entire table is wrapped in a div, with position: relative, for positioning of other things.

Comment: That does sound strange. The only thing i can think of is just play around with your padding and/or margins..